# How to add numerical values mapped to similar strings

Tags: excel, vba

I dumped a SQL query into Excel and am looking for a way to automate this.

Here's what I have.

```
site                             12
site/subsite                     22
another site                     77
another site/subsite             16
```

My question is this: is there a way in Excel to add totals for the site and its associated subsite? I have about 4000 rows so am looking to save manual labor.

Comment: Are sub/subsite always separated by "/", and is there always only one level of subsite (ie. no site/subsite/subsubsite) ?

Comment: There are sometimes two levels, but no more than that.

Comment: `=IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",A2)),A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1))` will pull out the "site" - you can then use SUMIF() as described by HoC to sum the "same" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SUMIF()` function.

Here is an example that can get you started:

Put your data in columns A and B (sites in A, values in B).

Add a column header in cell D1 that matches one of the sites names exactly.

Add this formula in cell D2:

```
=SUMIF($A6:$B17, D1, $B6:$B17)
```

Modify the start and end rows to cover your entire data set. (In the example I set up, the data was in rows 6 through 17.)

You can list all of your sites and subsites and have formulas refer to the data range to calculate totals for each.

Comment: I have variable subsites for each site. Is there a way to iterate through that or do I have to hard-code the cell range?

Comment: You can automate anything in Excel using VBA. Record a macro and then set your SUMIF formula as I outlined above. Stop the recording and the generated code should help you get started. If you get stuck, post your code and we can fix it.